# Can't get random number to work for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, settimeout

Can't seem to get my Random # to work at all - code won't execute :(

```
function getRandomInt (5000, 10000) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000 - 5000 + 1)) + 5000;
}

setTimeout(Greasemonkey_main, getRandomInt);

function Greasemonkey_main () {
unsafeWindow.submitform(0);
unsafeWindow.submitform(1);
unsafeWindow.submitform(2);
unsafeWindow.submitform(3);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that you can open up Firefox's error console (***Ctrl+Shift+J***) to see errors that code like this will throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `getRandomInt()` has syntax error(s). Use [the standard version of that function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527820/331508)!

So the code would become:

```
setTimeout (Greasemonkey_main, getRandomInt (5000, 10000) );

function Greasemonkey_main () {
    unsafeWindow.submitform(0);
    unsafeWindow.submitform(1);
    unsafeWindow.submitform(2);
    unsafeWindow.submitform(3);
}

function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor (Math.random () * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}
```

Comment: you're my hero :) - as you can tell I don't program alot - lol I research to the best of my ability but dont understand alot of the varibles and what not.

Comment: Glad to help. :)  Keep in mind that error console.  If the error message doesn't help you figure out the problem, including it in your question will get you more/faster/better response.